# ida shows instructions as hex data

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis

I am new to reverse engineering. I did a couple of projects. now I was doing another project and faced kind of a problem.

at the start of the program, there is a label that points to an address of memory but when going to that address there is only hex data instead of instruction.
how I can convert those to the instruction. I used "C (convert to code)" which was nonsense.
[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: `_CorExeMain` suggests .NET binary. Ida is not the proper tool for that file. Use `dnSpy` or alternative

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Got it. Thanks.